# Как при помощи phpDoc описать сразу два варианта метода, перегруженных через __call и __callStatic?

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

В классе есть два магических метода `__call` и `callStatic`, с помощью которых перегружается условный метод `read()`. В случае обращения к данному методу как к статическому, ему передается `id` сущности для чтения. В случае обращения к нему, как к методу экземпляра класса, ему ничего не передается, `id` берется из свойства экземпляра.

В обоих случаях возвращается один и тот же либо вновь созданный, либо уже существующий экземпляр класса. Перед классом я пробую записать вот так вот оба варианта метода, статический и нет:

```
/**
 * Class Entity
 *
 * @package MyCompany\Contracts
 *
 * @property array  $data
 * @property int    $id
 * @property string $name
 *
 * @method Entity read()
 * @method static Entity read( $id )
 */
```

Но PhpStorm 2019.1 ругается на такую запись вот так:

> Method with same name already defined in this class Another definition
>   with same name exists in this file

Кто прав, я или PhpStorm? Если я неправ, то как мне ублажить последнего?

Comment: @method Entity read() | static Entity read( $id )

Comment: @AntonKucenko а у вас получалось так использовать? У меня в итоге ругаться в самом классе на запись перестало, но зато при попытке обращения к методу ругается на то, что неверное количество аргументов - ну то есть статическую анализатору не видно, он смотрит только на первую, которая просто read().